# Download zip file from http api in react, Receiving error: "Unable to expand file.zip. It is an unsupported format"

Tags: reactjs, django, api, django-views, zip

Thanks in advance for taking a look. I am working on being able to download a zip file from react through a django api request. I am able to click on my pop up that downloads the zip file, but when I double click on the zip file to open, I get this error: "Unable to expand file_name.zip. It is an unsupported format" My response with the zip file seems to be passing correctly to the front end, so I am thinking it may be something wrong with the react code when making the "blob"? Thanks again.

Django code:

```
class DownloadZip(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):

        # information to find file to create zip
        profile_name = request.data["profile"]
        profile_year = request.data["year"]
        
        # file path to create zips from
        path = str(Path(__file__).parent.resolve())
                
        zip_dir = shutil.make_archive(profile_name + profile_year, "zip", path + "/" + profile_name + profile_year)

        s = io.StringIO(zip_dir)

        response = HttpResponse(s, content_type = "application/zip")

        zip_name = profile_name + profile_year + ".zip"

        response["Content-Disposition"] = f"attachment; filename={zip_name}"
        
        return response
```

React code:

```
    downloadZip = async () => {
        const params = {
            profile: this.state.profileName,
            year: this.state.year,
        };
        axios({
            url: `${serverUrl}/download_zip`,
            method: "post",
            data: params
        }).then(
            (res) => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data],{type:'application/zip'}));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'file.zip');
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
```

I did do a fellow commentor's suggestion, and updated to get route with query params, but am having the same issue. I can double click on the zip link on the web browser but a pop up appears "Unable to expand filename.zip. It is an unsupported format"

Comment: It is weird that you are using HTTP post method to download a file, Use HTTP GET instead

Comment: Unfortunately I have to pass through some data to find the file that corresponds to the choices, to return the correct zip. Get doesn't work with passing this data through

Comment: You can use *query parameters*

Comment: I will attempt this and update if this fixes the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I changed it to get with query params, receiving same error

Comment: Did you try asking on https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zip ?

Answer (score 3):

Please try adding {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}. I also had the same problem but after adding this {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}. I am getting correct file.

```
 downloadZip = async () => {
        const params = {
            profile: this.state.profileName,
            year: this.state.year,
        };
        axios.post(
              `${serverUrl}/download_zip`,
              params,
              {
                  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
              }
        ).then(
            (res) => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data],{type:'application/zip'}));
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', 'file.zip');
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
```